# Spring+Cassandra+Solr Grouping

Tags: solr, cassandra, spring-data-solr

Is it possible to grouping  data more than one field by using [SolrTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/SolrTemplate.html)

example, i want to group by id and name in a table

Answer (score 1):

As the [group options returns a list of group by fields](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/query/GroupOptions.html#getGroupByFields--) you can probably do something like this:

```
Query query = new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria("*:*"));

SimpleQuery groupQuery = new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria("*:*"));

GroupOptions groupOptions = new GroupOptions()
                .addGroupByField("id")
                .addGroupByField("name")
                .addGroupByQuery(query);

groupQuery.setGroupOptions(groupOptions);

GroupPage<Foo> page = solrTemplate.queryForGroupPage(query, Foo.class);
```

Read more in the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.misc.group).